# Importing data from file to ElasticSearch with logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I have script that logs temperature + humidity from diffrent sensors and stores the data from each sensor to his directory and every day a new log is made in this format YYYY-MM-DD.log.

```
${data_root}/A/0/*.log 
${data_root}/A/1/*.log
ETC..
```

the logs are in this format:

```
2018-03-02 03:48:14 25.00 27.10
```

(YYYY-MM-DD TIME Temperature Humidity)

I had trouble with understanding how to correctly config my logstash instance, I figured that my input should look something like this:

```
input {
 file{ path => "/var/wlogs/a1/*.log" type=>"a1"}
 file{ path => "/var/wlogs/a2/*.log" type=>"a2"}
etc..
}
```

and the filter should look something like this:

```
filter{
if [type] == "a1" {
 grok {
  match => { "message" => "(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM:month}-%{MONTHDAY:day} %{TIME}) %{NUMBER:temperature:float} %{NUMBER:humidity:float}" }
}
}
if [type] == "a2" {....}
```

Im trying to export the the data in the output section to ElasticSearch with no success.

```
output{
elasticsearch { hosts =>["ec2-xxxxxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9200"] user=>"elastic" password=>"pass" index=>"{type}"}
stdout{ codec => rubydebug}
}
```

here is the console output when I try to run it:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xxx:/usr/share/logstash$ sudo bin/logstash -f ~/logstash.conf
WARNING: Could not find logstash.yml which is typically located in $LS_HOME/config or /etc/logstash. You can specify the path using --path.settings. Continuing using the defaults
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path /usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties. Using default config which logs errors to the console
[INFO ] 2018-03-02 13:43:34.633 [main] scaffold - Initializing module {:module_name=>"fb_apache", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
[INFO ] 2018-03-02 13:43:34.647 [main] scaffold - Initializing module {:module_name=>"netflow", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/netflow/configuration"}
[WARN ] 2018-03-02 13:43:35.063 [LogStash::Runner] multilocal - Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[INFO ] 2018-03-02 13:43:35.209 [LogStash::Runner] runner - Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.2.2"}
[INFO ] 2018-03-02 13:43:35.430 [Api Webserver] agent - Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[INFO ] 2018-03-02 13:43:36.145 [Ruby-0-Thread-1: /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/task.rb:22] pipeline - Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>2, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
[INFO ] 2018-03-02 13:43:36.318 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elastic:xxxxxx@ec2-no.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9200/]}}
[INFO ] 2018-03-02 13:43:36.327 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://elastic:xxxxxx@ec2-no.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9200/, :path=>"/"}
[WARN ] 2018-03-02 13:43:36.447 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elastic:xxxxxx@ec2-3no3.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9200/"}
[INFO ] 2018-03-02 13:43:36.610 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - ES Output version determined {:es_version=>nil}
[WARN ] 2018-03-02 13:43:36.611 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>6}
[INFO ] 2018-03-02 13:43:36.616 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
[INFO ] 2018-03-02 13:43:36.619 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
[INFO ] 2018-03-02 13:43:36.626 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//ec2-no.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9200"]}
[INFO ] 2018-03-02 13:43:37.054 [Ruby-0-Thread-1: /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/task.rb:22] pipeline - Pipeline started succesfully {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x25b5f422@/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:246 run>"}
[INFO ] 2018-03-02 13:43:37.081 [Ruby-0-Thread-1: /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/task.rb:22] agent - Pipelines running {:count=>1, :pipelines=>["main"]}
```

please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it :)
thanks in advance

P.S: Im using the latest versions of ElasticSearch, Kibana and Logstash

Answer (score 0):

Don't see any error in the logs. Makes me think that the log files might have already been read in a previous attempt. Since the file offsets are maintained in the sincedb file in home directory, can you stop logstash, delete the file and try again?

For more details about the sincedb file, refer to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html